# for loop with dplyr summarise returning different results than group_by

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm getting strange results when applying `for` loop on `dplyr` summarise function - not sure why or how to fix it.

```
test <- data.frame(title = c("a", "b", "c","a","b","c", "a", "b", "c","a","b","c"),
                       category = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                       sex = c("m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f"),
                       salary = c(50,70,90,40,60,85, 220,270,350,180,200,330))

category_list <- unique(test$category)

tmp = list()

for (category in category_list) {
  # Create an average salary line for the category
  tmp[category] <- test %>% 
    filter(category == category) %>%
    summarise(mean(salary))
  print(tmp)
}
```

I get this as output

```
$A
[1] 162.0833

$A
[1] 162.0833

$B
[1] 162.0833
```

Where as the `group_by()` function returns the appropriate result:

```
    test %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(mean(salary))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  category `mean(salary)`
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 A                  65.8
2 B                 258.
```

Substituting a specific category *does* return the appropriate result though:

```
test %>% 
        filter(category == "A") %>%
        summarise(mean(salary))
      mean(salary)
1     65.83333
```

So maybe it was something wrong with the `category_list` object?
Surprisingly when I call the first element of the `category_list` object I'm also getting the appropriate answer:

```
test %>% 
+     filter(category == category_list[1]) %>%
+     summarise(mean(salary))
  mean(salary)
1     65.83333
```

The reason why I want to figure this out (and not use `group_by`) is because I'm trying to make a script that will create a number of ggplot objects which will then be combined with the `gridExtra` library.

Maybe I'm wrong and `group_by` can be used but the only way I can think of doing this is with the following pseudocode:

- 1) create a list of means by `category` to be used in the `geom_hline()` parameter
- 2) subset a data frame object by `category`, each subset will be used in ggplot with its `geom_hline()`
- 3) create a list of plot objects for each `category`
- 4) use `grid.arrange()` from `gridExtra` library outside of the `for` loop to combine each plot together

This is my code so far (not working):

```
library(gridExtra)
p = list()
avg_line = list()
tmp = list()
category_data = data.frame()
for (category in category_list) {
  # Create an average salary line for the category
  tmp[[category]] <- test %>% 
    filter(category == category) %>%
    summarise(mean(salary))
  avg_line[[category]] <- tmp[[2]]

  # Subset data frame on category 
  category_data[[category]] <- test %>% filter(category == category)

  # Make plots for each category
  p[[category]] <-
    ggplot(category_data[[category]], aes(x = title, y = salary)) +
  geom_line(color = "white") +
  geom_point(aes(color =sex)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#F49171", "#81C19C")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = avg_line[[category]], color = "white", alpha = 0.6, size = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
      panel.background = element_rect(color = "#242B47", fill = "#242B47"),
      plot.background = element_rect(color = "#242B47", fill = "#242B47"),
      axis.line = element_line(color = "grey48", size = 0.05, linetype = "dotted"),
      axis.text = element_text(family = "Georgia", color = "white"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
      # Get rid of the y- and x-axis titles
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey48", size = 0.05),
      panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
}

grid.arrange(grobs = p, nrow = 1)
```

My desired output would be this:

[image: toy example]

Comment: Couldn't you do something like `yintercept = mean(category_data[[category]]$salary)` rather than going to the trouble of making a new dataset?  To be honest, I find this sort of task most straightforward if I split things into a list of data.frames by group via `split` and then use an `lapply` or `purrr::map` loop for making the plots.

Comment: Here is a `split`-`map` example if you are up to pursuing a different strategy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572595/2461552

Comment: What is up with this? filter(category == category) .  You are comparing category to itself, of course the answers are going to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem within your for-loop is the statement `filter(category == category)`.  This is always true, because it's pulling `category` from your data both times.  If you really want your for-loop, just rename the iterator in your for loop.

However, you don't need `grid.arrange` at all.  `facet_wrap` gives you exactly what you are looking for (you might need to do a little reformatting of the facet labels, these are controlled using theme elements beginning with `strip`):

```
category_means <- test %>% 
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(salary), mean)

p <- test %>%
  # group_by(category) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = title, y = salary, color = sex)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ category, nrow = 1, scales = "free_y") +  
  geom_line(color = 'white') + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#F49171", "#81C19C")) +
  geom_hline(data = category_means, aes(yintercept = salary), color = 'white', alpha = 0.6, size = 1) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
    panel.background = element_rect(color = "#242B47", fill = "#242B47"),
    plot.background = element_rect(color = "#242B47", fill = "#242B47"),
    axis.line = element_line(color = "grey48", size = 0.05, linetype = "dotted"),
    axis.text = element_text(family = "Georgia", color = "white"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
    # Get rid of the y- and x-axis titles
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey48", size = 0.05),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
p
```